# How is this jQuery code creating an event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose I have this code:

```
$('#button').on('click', function () {
    $('#status').text('doing some work....');
    somethingThatTakes20Seconds('#status');
});
```

Here, `somethingThatTakes20Seconds` will be executed before the "doing some work" statement. While I understand the statement itself creates a DOM event which gets placed into the event queue and waits until the stack is clear to execute, what I don't get is how it's doing it (on a high level). Is the `.text` method asynchronous, in the same way like `setTimeout()` is (just with `.text` you don't take any callback, or is the callback auto-generated, basically some code that updates the DOM)?

Comment: _"Here, somethingThatTakes20Seconds will be executed before the "doing some work" statement."_ Can create stacksnippets to demonstrate ?

Comment: Setting text is not asynchronous. Issue makes no sense based on code shown. Provide a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that replicates this. Also what does `somethingThatTakes20Seconds()` actually do?

Comment: does `somethingThatTakes20Seconds` take 20 seconds to perform a task as is implied, or does it, in fact, wait 20 seconds (i.e. setTimeout) to perform a task - at least an idea of the core functionality of that function would be helpful in determining what you are seeing, because  the call to the function will always take place AFTER #status text is set to "doing some work" - ALWAYS

Comment: Suppose somethingThatTakes20Seconds  is something heavily computational that has no side effect and just takes 20 seconds to complete. Nothing to do with setTimeout inside somethingThatTakes20Seconds.

Comment: @daremkd Can  _"Here, somethingThatTakes20Seconds will be executed before the "doing some work" statement."_ be reproduced ?

Comment: Setting the text of the element is synchronous, but the browser doesn't repaint the screen until the current synchronous JS completes, so you don't see the effect of setting the text until after the 20-second function returns.

Comment: @nnnnnn so basically .text creates a DOM event as a side effect that will be added in the event queue and executed as ordinary callbacks?

Comment: The DOM is immediately updated. It's the repaint of the screen that is delayed until after the JS completes. If one block of code changed the text of four different elements that would be four DOM updates that happen immediately, and if code towards the end of that block then queried the text of the same elements it would see the new values, but the browser would only redraw the screen once, after the JS completes.

Answer (score 0):

The `text()` method is not asynchronous.  `$('#status').text('doing some work....');` will execute before `somethingThatTakes20Seconds('#status');`.

You can define your `somethingThatTakes20Seconds()` method to register a callback - which internally adds a listener to the JavaScript engine.  When the listener "hears" something - ie. an AJAX request is completely or an user performs an action, it adds an item to the message queue.

This is where the event loop comes in.  The event loop takes this message queue item and then calls the callback function associated with it.

Comment: doesn't explain what OP is seeing. What listener are you talking about?

Comment: @charlietfl I think the OP is confused about what is happening.  It is impossible for his custom function to be executed before the `text()`method.

Comment: I agree but reading explanation about `listeners` is very confusing also. Personally i don't get what you are saying

Comment: I understand it will be called, but will it create an event that will update the DOM (thus working in the same way like setTimeout?) Or will it block until the DOM is updated with the approprate text?

Comment: @daremkd It will block until the DOM is updated since it's an pure I/O event.

Answer (score 0):

The browser will not render the DOM to show the "doing some work..." message until after the function returns. Assuming your `somethingThatTakes20Seconds` function does not return for 20 seconds, you will not see that message for 20 seconds. You probably want to do something like this:

```
$('#button').on('click', function () {
    $('#status').text('doing some work....');
    setTimeout(function () { somethingThatTakes20Seconds('#status'); }, 10);
});
```

This will allow the DOM to be rendered before starting the long-running process.

For example: https://jsfiddle.net/9eq85udz/2/

Comment: please make a demo that shows this behavior. `$('#status').text('doing some work....');` will happen immediately contrary to your statement.

Comment: @charlietfl "In most browsers, rendering and JavaScript use single event queue. It means that while JavaScript is running, no rendering occurs." http://javascript.info/tutorial/events-and-timing-depth#javascript-execution-and-rendering

Comment: create a demo that does that

Comment: @charlietfl - my understanding is that the DOM will be updated immediately, so if another line later in the same function were to retrieve the text of that element it would get the new value, but *the browser does not repaint the screen until the current synchronous JS completes*. I don't have time to create a demo, but I'm certain that's how older browsers work - never needed to test it with the latest browsers, because I try not to write blocking code.

Comment: I see the confusion. "Update" vs. "render", not a good choice of words. The DOM will be updated, yes. However it will not be rendered to show the changes until after the JavaScript completes. Fixed.

Comment: @charlietfl Added fiddle (note it waits for 2 seconds, not 20). I observe the described behavior in IE 11 and Chrome 47 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

No, `.text()` method is not asynchronous.

**JavaScript only executes your code each line in sequence. It does not wait until each line execution is completed to execute the next line.**

In your code, basically what you're doing is:

1. *Change the `#status` text to `doing some work....`.*
2. *Run `somethingThatTakes20Seconds()` function.*

It's just impossible for your function to do the *2nd* function for 20 seconds, and then run the `1st` one considering how fast it is to run the `1st` function.

*Consider the following sample,*

```js
function addTextOne() {
  $('#result').append('This is text 1.\n');
}

function addTextTwo() {
  $('#result').append('This is text 2.\n');
}
$(function() {
  $("#testBtn").on('click', function() {
    setTimeout(addTextOne, 1001);
    setTimeout(addTextTwo, 1000);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="testBtn">
  Test
</button>
<br/>
<textarea id="result" cols='70' rows='30'></textarea>
```

*Note: The code sample basically executes `addTextOne` before `addTextTwo` on button click. But, `addTextTwo` finishes earlier than `addTextOne`.*

Comment: Maybe I have used the wrong word...this code will execute first, but when will the DOM change happen and hy? Will .text return immediately and create a DOM event or will it block until the DOM is updated?

Comment: @daremkd The DOM changes once the script finishes executing. So yeah, your `.text()` returns immediately.